# How to make a circle follow a line in python

Tags: python, tkinter

Here I have a code where I can make a line from different points, and I'm trying to make it so that when pressing play or a similar button, a circle goes from the first point to the last following the drawn line. Eventually, I would like to make it so that it passes through certain points at a specific time, but for now, I just want it to move on its own following whatever line is created. One way I thought to do this was to get the points from the line and make the circle go from point to point, but I have been unable to find a way to get the points from the line. If anyone has a way of doing it or an alternative it would be welcomed.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

line = []

def click(click_event):
    global line
    point = [click_event.x, click_event.y]
    
    line.append([point[0],point[1]])
    if len(line)>1:
        canvas.delete('all')
        canvas.create_line(line, width=2, smooth=1)


canvas = Canvas(root, bg='white')
canvas.pack(padx=20, pady=20)



canvas.bind('<Button-1>', click)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So what's the problem you are facing in doing that?

Comment: @Art That the number of actual points is limited and in some cases, the list of points saved in the line are not the ones actually shown on the drawn line so it's not like I can make the circle appear in the points as it would just be jumping around and not actually following the line.